# I am working to make a d3 family tree with two parents and want to move their siblings as children add on

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working to make a d3 family tree. Here I want the parents siblings to move along with their family whenever I add children so that the children their wont overlap  and the connection line between then remains in the middle.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ujLvca2/4/)

here is the code for sepration:

```
var treemap = d3.tree().size(width,height)
.nodeSize([width/2, height/5]).separation(function(d) {
if(d.data.no_parent)
    {return (0.11);}

else
    return 0.3
});
```

This(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKRrd.jpg) is what happens when I add children after there are already three